# Application error: a server-side exception has occurred (see the server logs for more information). Digest: 3125597724 while deploying next app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server, vercel, payload

Please, somebody! Every time I try to deploy my next app to Vercel I get this error on my page (the build seems alright, the site is deployed). env variables seem fine as well. for the localhost the website with the mongoDB atlas database run well. Here are my logs: [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pQG5.png)

That's this /api/users/me it complains about: [/api/users/me] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khnpq.png)

I use payload, but on my local it seems like there were no such incidents.

I overlooked and changed all env. variables, re-compiled, reinstalled - still no solution. My payload seems fine as well, all variables are on places, but still somewhat it errors me. If somebody could help me with this, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: You should inspect the network diagnostic tab in your browser and identify what is actually being sent from the server;  "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" Almost always indicates that HTML is coming back from the server rather than JSON data.  Viewing the contents of this HTML will probably help you identify what is going wrong.

Comment: It seems like an error was with the function timeout limit on one of my APIs for vercel, thank you